# How to print index in a 'for-loop' being executed in remote host through SSH?

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to ssh into a remote host, and then execute a for loop that goes through sequence of numbers to control number of different nodes.

```
ssh user@host /bin/bash << EOF
for i in {1..10}
do
echo $i
done
EOF
```

If I do this, the output is just 10 blank lines, instead of printing out numbers from 1 through 10.

If I execute same code on my local machine, I get the desired output which is ten lines each line printing from 1 through 10.

How would one achieve the intended functionality, that is accessing the index in a for loop that is being executed in SSH?

Comment: did you try eval? I suspect the `$i` is expanded locally, before sending it over via ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [bash manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Here Documents
>   The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> <<[-]word
>         here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> [...] If any characters in word are
>   quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the
>   lines in the here-document are not expanded. If word is unquoted, all
>   lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion,
>   command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.

Let's try it:

```
$ i='Howdy!'
$ ssh user@localhost /bin/bash << EOF
for i in {1..10}
do
echo $i
done
EOF
Howdy!
Howdy!
Howdy!
Howdy!
Howdy!
Howdy!
Howdy!
Howdy!
Howdy!
Howdy!
$ ssh user@localhost /bin/bash << 'EOF'
for i in {1..10}
do
echo $i
done
EOF
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$
```